# Enforcing type of attribute parameter

Tags: c#, attributes

Is there a way to enforce that a type parameter passed to an attribute implement specific interface?

```
public interface IExpectedInterface
{
    void InterfaceMethod();
}

public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute(Type classType)
    {
        this.ConfirmAssignedClassType();

        _classType = classType;
    }

    public void SomeMethod<T>() where T : IExpectedInterface, new()
    {
        //var expectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(this._classType) as IExpectedInterface;
        var expectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as IExpectedInterface;

        if (expectedType == null)
        {
            // Wrong type

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Wrong type: {0} could not be created or converted to IActionAuthorization", _classType.ToString()));
        }

        // Do something with expectedType

        expectedType.InterfaceMethod();
    }

    private void ConfirmAssignedClassType()
    {
        if (!typeof(IExpectedInterface).IsAssignableFrom(_classType))
        {
            // Wrong type
            // Can we enforce it via language construct

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Wrong type: {0} must implement IExpectedInterface", _classType.ToString()));
        }

        if (this._classType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null)
        {
            // Wrong type
            // Can we enforce it via language construct

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Wrong type: {0} must have parameter less constructor", _classType.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private Type _classType;
}

public class TestClass
{
    [MyCustom(typeof(TestClassImplementsExpectedInterface))]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }

    [MyCustom(typeof(TestClassDoesntImplementExpectedInterface))]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
    }
}

public class TestClassImplementsExpectedInterface : IExpectedInterface
{
    public void InterfaceMethod()
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class TestClassDoesntImplementExpectedInterface
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't this be done with generics? (Edited -- cannot create a generic subclass of Attribute)

```
   public class MyAttribute: Attribute 
    {
        private Type _ClassType;
        public MyAttribute(Type classType)
        {
            _ClassType = classType;
        }
        public void SomeMethod<T>() where T: IMyInterface
        {
            var expectedType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as IMyInterface;
        // Do something with expectedType
        }
    }
```

And of course the other answer's translation to use "new" makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Not according to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173129(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: You are correct, and in fact, it does not compile with a very specific error! I threw something into VS and there were no intellisense errors, so I wrongly assumed it was valid. How odd.

Comment: ... so on to the "if you really wanted" alternative.

Comment: I only know because I had the same idea and thought I would see if it would work...

Comment: Doesn't make any difference in compile time, see updated code.

Comment: If you tried to call `SomeMethod` with something that didn't implement `IExpectedInterface` it shouldn't compile.

Comment: .. that is to say .. you could still create an instance of the class with an invalid type since there's no constraint on the class itself, but presumably you actually call `SomeMethod` at some point, so the compiler should choke then.

Comment: @jamietre, within the attribute, I don't know the concrete type.

Comment: The attribute I am working with is actually ActionFilterAttribute. So I am not really calling any method on it. I am only overriding some methods.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you don't want to mess with generics (such as putting all the attributes into a list or something), there is what might be considered a slightly better way, though still without compile-time checking. You can call the Type.IsAssignableFrom method, instead of calling Activator.CreateInstance (which might or might not work depending on whether there are 0-param ctors) (though it seems like you assume that there is a 0-param ctor, so this might be somewhat moot).

```
if (!typeof(SomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(_ClassType)))
// Throw exception
```

Comment: This is probably the better way to go then - if you were to store the `Type` parameter in a property, and put this code in the setter, your attribute would enforce the interface inheritance implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your method to being generic, e.g.

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public void SomeMethod<T>() where T : ISomeInterface, new()
    {
        var expectedType = new T();
        // Do something with expectedType
    }
}
```

The `new()` type constraint means that the type must have a public, parameterless constructor which means you can do `new T()`. This removes the need to use `Activator`.

Note that, as Duncan Howe points out, a generic type cannot inherit from `Attribute`, so you cannot do `public class MyAttribute<T> : Attribute`

Comment: Doesn't make any difference in compile time, see updated code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. this should work if your intention is to limit the types that can be used to only those inheriting from a given interface

Comment: Within the attribute I don't know the concrete type. So this compiles even though in the TestMethod2 the attribute is passed incorrect type.

Comment: The attribute I am working with is actually ActionFilterAttribute. So I am not really calling any method on it. I am only overriding some methods.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not just pass the object in through the constructor (e.g. `Public MyAttribute(IMyInterface myObject)`) and store it in a property. Then if you need the type, explicitly call `typeof(myObjectProperty)`.

Comment: Any attribute arguments must be constants, typeof expressions, and can't be things like "new Foo()".

Comment: Very true - should have known (I've been in that pit!)